# Flickering issue on changepage

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I was working on mobile aaplication using intel xdk.

I want to load products on productList page depending on `categorid` sent from home page

```
$('img.categories').bind("click",function(){

                    ProductList.categoryId=$(this).data('value');
                    $.mobile.changePage('productlist.html')

                });

  var ProductList={
         categoryId:null,
         init:function(){

                       this.loadProducts();

                        },
         loadProducts:function(){

    //code to load products depending on categoryid

                                }
},
```

But when I click on any image to loadproducts. Product list is opened and again home page is shown and then again product list page. this scenario happens on my other pages as well. 
Functionality is working properly, but this flickering issue is there.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior on the device or in the xdk emulator?  Any chance you could provide a more complete runnable test case?

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide on device only not in emulator! :). Well talking about runnable case how can i because its working proper on desktop

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar flickering issue in Ionic, I changed the CSS and it worked.

```
  .ui-page {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/14/eliminating-annoying-flicker-transitions-with.html